# ajax load function not working in ie 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

ajax load function working in chrome, safari, opera, firefox but not working in internet explorer 8. (jquery version "jquery-1.11.2")

js code

```
function solFrame(islem, sayfa) {
    if (sayfa == '') {
        sayfa = 1;
    }
    $('#solx').html('<div style="text-align:center"><img src="./images/yuklen.gif"></div>');
    $("#solx").load('sozluk.php?process=' + islem + '&page=' + sayfa);
    return false;
}
```

and php/html code

```
<p onclick="solFrame('today','1');">today</p>
```

I need your help...

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: ... jQuery 2.X.X doesn't support IE<9.

Comment: ... and why would you be using inline event handlers like `onclick` with any version of jQuery ?

Comment: i'm using jquery version = jquery-1.11.2.js @adeneo

Comment: Look in the developer tools, should give an indication why.

Comment: I can not solve this problem @EternalHour

Comment: Well we can't solve it for you unless you provide more information. You should be able to get an error in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Caution with IE: The innerHTML property is read-only on the col, colGroup, frameSet, html, head, style, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, title, and tr objects.

It can break your ajax load if you do in any of these elements.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can create a whole table by using `innerHTML` though.